# Rename git remote name to "upstream"

Tags: windows, git, shell, git-remote, git-fork

I have a tiny problem with my git setup. I am working with forked repositories quite often. To fork them, I use the button on GitHub. After that, the command `git remote -v` shows me "origin" and "original-username".

"original-username" is now the upstream branch where I can pull changes from and create pull requests too. I would like to have this named "upstream" though.
That would make it easier to use the same commands on different forks, and I can even create aliases with that.

So I know I can change the remote name with `git remote rename original-username upstream`, but that would mean I have to do it for every fork, every time I get that fork on a machine, and I have to make git remote -v first etc, and I am lazy :P
Also original-username is different on every fork.

So my question is:
**Is there a possibility to rename the remote branch (from different names) to upstream, maybe with a cool alias function or a small script?**

My dream woudl something like this:

```
[alias]
    setupstream = "!f(){ git remote rename $oldupstream upstream; };f"
```

`$oldupstream` should be gotten automatically, in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the assumption that a local repository will only have two remote's configured where one is `origin` and the other is the one you want to rename something like this should work.

```
setupstream = "!f() { \
    local rem=$(git remote | grep -v '^origin$'); \
    if [ \"$(wc -l <<<\"$rem\")\" -gt 1 ]; then \
        echo 'Too many remotes.' >&2; \
        return; \
    fi; \
    if [ -z \"$rem\" ]; then \
        echo 'No non-origin remote found.' >&2; \
        return; \
    fi; \
    if [ \"$rem\" = upstream ]; then \
        echo '\"upstream\" remote already exists.'; \
        return; \
    fi; \
    git remote rename \"$rem\" upstream; \
    echo \"Renamed $rem to upstream.\"; \
}; f"
```

Comment: Hey! That function looks really nicely, that should be what I am searching for. Bad thing about that is that it is not working in my windows environment. It tells me invalid config then. If found [this](https://medium.com/@vitalyb/creating-powerful-git-aliases-3dfc0efc9a31) how to use such functions on windows, but while trying to change it, I can't get it to work. My current function looks like [this](https://gist.github.com/Wolfsblvt/74f4ddba00c03b59eb63), wich only echoes some test. Can you maybe help me to convert your function to work for windows?

Comment: You probably need to add semicolons to the ends of the lines to terminate the statements. I meant to put those in the post. I'll add them now.

Comment: Brilliant! I had to add slashes after the "then" rows too (I think they are for escaping the newline char?), then it worked. Now I have even added a success message and it does all what I wanted. I thank you very much!

Comment: Bah, yeah, you need slashes after the `then` lines but not semicolons. Sorry.

Comment: Also can just add as bash function to `~/.bashrc` without the trailing slashes, `\"`  escapes, and turn it into a bash function.